# Is it possible for PHP & AJAX to clash an insert a query twice?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

So I'm making a basic chat box out of PHP/PDO/AJAX and recently when I added the AJAX code it and submit my shout it runs the query twice, I have had my code checked and the checker said they can't see anything wrong. So I was wondering if you could help me find the error instead.

shout.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shout!</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css"/>
</head>  
</html>

<?php

include 'auth.login.php';
include 'pdo.config.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
echo '<br/>';
echo '<center>You need to login to post!<br/>';
header("Refresh:2; URL=index.php");
exit();
}

$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];

if (!isset($_POST['Message']) || empty($_POST['Message'])) {
echo '<br/>';
echo '<center>How do you expect to send a message if the field is empty, ey?<br/>';
header("Refresh:2; URL=index.php");
exit();
} else {

$Message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']);

$insertMessage = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `chatbox` (User, Message) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insertMessage->bindParam(1, $Username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertMessage->bindParam(2, $Message, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($insertMessage->execute()) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<center>Aw snap, shout could not be added!';
    header("Refresh:2; URL=index.php");
    exit();
}
}

?>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({

    url: 'data.php',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data)
    { 
$.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
$('#messageDisplay').append("<div>["+elem.SentOn+"] "+elem.User+": "
+ elem.Message + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
});
```

my form:

```
<form action="shout.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="8" cols="74" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Post messages here."></textarea> 
<br/><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Shout!">
                </form>
```

data.php

```
<?php

include 'pdo.config.php';


$chat = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM `chatbox`");
$getRow = $chat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($getRow);

?>
```

Comment: @djot, Added data.php.

Comment: "my form:" -- which file is the form in, index.php?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong other than shout.php outputting html after closing html tag.

Comment: @developerwjk, Yes it is.

Comment: @KevinB, same so what could the issue be?

Comment: you're using a regular html form rather than ajax in index.php?

Comment: @developerwjk, Would that affect it?

Comment: For the sake of my curiosity, could you remove the output before your header() gets sent down in shout.php - I'm looking specifically at the `execute` condition's else statement [and the block at the top of the page] which serves output then sends the header.  I'm not expecting it to fix the problem but nothing else potentially problematic is jumping out at me.

Comment: @Ross, removed and tested, still no luck.

Comment: The issue could be, not related to what you've shown us thus far.

Comment: Before header no output...

Comment: @KevinB, well, those are all the files related to it, other files are just a class file with options currently containing one truncate table option and the DB connection file.

Comment: @T_01, I just started learning today erm so that may be a problem for me sorry.

Comment: Just basic logic. If the problem doesn't appear to be here, it must be elsewhere. Try reducing your code to a smaller sample. Remove the database from the equation. remove the ajax from the equation. (not both at once.)

Comment: As Kevin B says, I think we might need a bit more context.  Couple of questions that come up next:  What's the rest of your form's page / any javascript?  Does auth do any redirecting?

Comment: @Ross, The rest of the form page is bits and bobs of HTML/PHP nothing to do with Inserting anything. No JS.

Comment: Curious.  Last ditch things are checking your log files [and if you have it set up, use a debugger to walk through your shout.php file].  Does your access.log show just one access to the shout.php file on submission?  Check your error.log for anything that might stand out just for thoroughness...

Comment: Just another debugging tip.  Run the page in a Browser with a developer tool that will show the requests made and check for duplication.  For example in Chrome from the menu, select tools, developer tools,  and browse to the network tab.  May shed some light.

Comment: @Ross, I tried, both data.php and main.js access the file along with shout.php. However it does say 302 & Found if that affects it.

Comment: Sorry @Script47, I'm not clear.  Just to be precise is there more than one line in your access log after you send a new submission that, right after the [timestamp] has "POST /your/path/data.php" - if so, that would trigger two inserts... a very long shot I'm afraid and anything more would require full code samples [for me, someone else may have ideas!].  Best of luck.

Comment: @Ross, Is it possible to take this to a private chat by any chance I will shot you everything?

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to try but no guarantees!

Comment: @Ross, How do we do it?

Comment: http://webchat.freenode.net/  is one option - just join the channel `#so-php-quick`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36819/discussion-between-script47-and-ross)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step is to check your access.log to ensure you're not getting a double POST from somewhere to shout.php

There may be other posts happening that have slipped under the radar.